# Removing string unicode marks from list and having each item on separate line

Tags: python, csv, unicode, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I have a list, listOfActors, that contains sublists of actors in each movie from data found on this website - http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?yr=2013&p=.htm.

I get the actors using a webcrawling function

```
def getActors(item_url):
    response = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")  # or BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
    tempActors = []
    try:
        tempActors.append(soup.find(text="Actors:").find_parent("tr").find_all(text=True)[1:])
    except AttributeError:
        tempActors.append("n/a")
    return tempActors
```

The result is a list of the actors in this format

```
[u'Jennifer Lawrence', u'Josh Hutcherson', u'Liam Hemsworth', u'Elizabeth Banks', u'Stanley Tucci', u'Woody Harrelson', u'Philip Seymour Hoffman', u'Jeffrey Wright', u'Jena Malone', u'Amanda Plummer', u'Sam Claflin', u'Donald Sutherland', u'Lenny Kravitz']
[u'Robert Downey, Jr.', u'Gwyneth Paltrow', u'Don Cheadle', u'Guy Pearce', u'Rebecca Hall', u'James Badge Dale', u'Jon Favreau', u'Ben Kingsley', u'Paul Bettany*', u' ', u'(Voice)', u'Mark Ruffalo*', u' ', u'(Cameo)']
```

I export this data into a csv file, and each of these lists is on a separate row. I have two questions:

First, how can I remove the "u'" marks from each of the sub lists, and preferably also the brackets?

Second, when I open the csv file, I want each of the actors to be in it's own block in excel. Right now they are all in one giant block.

> I want the final output to be like:
>
> Jennifer Lawrence |Josh Hutcherson|Liam Hemsworth|... so on and so
>   forth
>
> Robert Downey, Jr. | Gwyneth Paltrow|Don Cheadle|

instead of

```
[u'Jennifer Lawrence', u'Josh Hutcherson', u'Liam Hemsworth', u'Elizabeth Banks', u'Stanley Tucci', u'Woody Harrelson', u'Philip Seymour Hoffman', u'Jeffrey Wright', u'Jena Malone', u'Amanda Plummer', u'Sam Claflin', u'Donald Sutherland', u'Lenny Kravitz']

[u'Robert Downey, Jr.', u'Gwyneth Paltrow', u'Don Cheadle', u'Guy Pearce', u'Rebecca Hall', u'James Badge Dale', u'Jon Favreau', u'Ben Kingsley', u'Paul Bettany*', u' ', u'(Voice)', u'Mark Ruffalo*', u' ', u'(Cameo)']
```

This is my main webcrawling function where I call the getActors function:

```
def spider(max_pages):
    page = 1
    while page <= max_pages:
        url = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com/yearly/chart/?page=' + str(page) + '&view=releasedate&view2=domestic&yr=2013&p=.htm'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.select('td > b > font > a[href^=/movies/?]'):
             href = 'http://www.boxofficemojo.com' + link.get('href')
            listOfActors.append(getActors(href))
        page += 1
```

Comment: Please show the complete code you have including the part where you export to csv.

Comment: I see you got your scraper to work ;)

Comment: `s = map(lambda x: x.encode('ascii'),s)` will convert it to ascii (remove the u)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you should change your current implementation of getActors to this. Your current implementation returns a list of list. This returns a single list.

```
def getActors(item_url):
    response = requests.get(item_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")  # or BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html5lib")
    tempActors = []
    try:
        return(soup.find(text="Actors:").find_parent("tr").find_all(text=True)[1:])
    except AttributeError:
        return ['n/a']
```

Then, after collecting a number of lists from `getActors` into a single list of lists called `listOfActors`, you can write them all to a csv file like this

```
out = open('csv.csv','w')
for i in listOfActors:
    line = ''
    for j in i:
        line = line+j+','
    out.write(line+'\n')

out.close()
```

Please use commas to separate the values. Also, python will automatically take care of unicode strings.

Comment: I'm getting an error - TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Would the person who down voted this please leave a comment?

Comment: @alphamonkey lxml is the best :D